# Creating sentence-level annotations from corpus-level annotations without loops

Tags: python, nltk, spacy

I'm given a list of annotations. The start and end position of each annotation correspond to the distance from the start of the corpus, but I want the positions to correspond to the distance from start of the current sentence.

Input: (Spans that indicate "fox" are from 10-13, 35-38, 50-53)

```
example = DocumentMulti(
    "The brown fox jumped over the lazy fox. The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog",
    [Span(10, 13, "fox", None), Span(35, 38, "fox", None), Span(50, 53, "fox", None)]
)
```

Output

```
sentencize_pubtator(example)

[DocumentMulti(text='The brown fox jumped over the lazy fox.', denotations=[Span(start=10, end=13, mention='fox', descriptor_record=None), Span(start=35, end=38, mention='fox', descriptor_record=None)]),
 DocumentMulti(text='The brown fox jumped over the lazy dog', denotations=[Span(start=10, end=13, mention='fox', descriptor_record=None)])]
```

I am trying to:

1. Split an abstract into multiple sentences
2. **Match the given annotations its respective sentence**
3. Update the start and end character positions to be wrt. the sentence rather than the abstract. In other words, the positions should represent the length from the beginning of the sentence.

My current code looks un-pythonic and was hoping for there another method that doesn't involve explicit loops. I was hoping to use a combination of `groupby()` to aggregate the spans based on the start and end indices of each sentence and `map()` to update the start and end of each span, but cannot get a solution.

[Colab Notebook with code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1s3Nq3FsyMm929NlVvw9NBqYLQMM2URpv?usp=sharing)

```
@dataclass
class Span:
    start: int
    end: int
    mention: str
    descriptor_record: DescriptorRecord


@dataclass
class DocumentMulti:
    text: str
    denotations: List[Span]
```

```
def sentencize_pubtator(document):
    # Splits sentences
    nlp = English()
    nlp.add_pipe("sentencizer")
    doc = nlp(document.text)
    
    # Dataframe for sentence-level annotations
    df = []
    
    # Index of abstract-annotation 
    i = 0
    for sentence in doc.sents:
        sent_denotations = []
        
        # (Step 2) Loops through each abstract-annotation that corresponds with the current sentence
        while (
            i < len(document.denotations)
            and int(document.denotations[i].start) >= sentence.start_char
            and int(document.denotations[i].end) <= sentence.end_char
        ):
            
            # (Step 3) Updates abstract-positions to sentence-positions
            document.denotations[i].start -= sentence.start_char
            document.denotations[i].end -= sentence.start_char
            sent_denotations.append(document.denotations[i])

            # Go to next abstract-annotation
            i += 1
        
        # Appends single sentence and corresponding annotations 
        df.append(DocumentMulti(str(sentence), sent_denotations))

    return df
```

Comment: You will be more likely to receive assistance if you prepare a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've simplified the example and provided a collab notebook to reproduce the code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1s3Nq3FsyMm929NlVvw9NBqYLQMM2URpv?usp=sharing

Comment: Include all relevant text/code here in the post, do not link to external locations of data/code.

Comment: I didn't. The link is not external code, but a live example of the code posted above. I didn't think I could use Stack Snippets b/c the code is in Python. Following Stack Overflow's [Help others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), I don't think I did anything wrong.